# Creating factor in dataset for statistical analysis

Tags: r, dataset

I have the following dataset:

```
Sites Var1  Var2   Var3
N1    246    392    56
N2    940    955    33
N3    190    402    193
N4    945    394    16
```

I need to analyze the difference between forest (N1 and N2) and desert (N3 and N4) groups. The statistical package (`Vegan`) requires me to create a factor for grouping the sites in those 2 groups.

I am reading how to create factors but I can't get it done so far.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is just creating two groups for forest (N1 and N2) and desert (N3 and N4) you can do the following:

```
> dataset$GroupFactor <- as.factor(ifelse(dataset$Sites %in% c("N1", "N2"), "Forest", "Desert"))
> dataset
  Sites Var1 Var2 Var3 GroupFactor
1    N1  246  392   56      Forest
2    N2  940  955   33      Forest
3    N3  190  402  193      Desert
4    N4  945  394   16      Desert
```

Checking what class `GroupFactor` is

```
> class(dataset$GroupFactor)
[1] "factor"
```